Sending 'multipart/form-data' from PowerShell using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]
I am working on creating a custom function (Invoke-WebExRequest) for interacting with WebEx API. I have it mostly working, but am unable to get it to work with 'multipart/form-data' data.
I am building my body manually (plain text). I am able to get it to work using 'Invoke-WebRequest' using the '-ContentType' switch, specifying the type and boundary.
This code block works for posting my multipart/form-data using Invoke-WebRequest:
$GUID = New-Guid

$Body = @"
------------$($GUID)------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roomId"

$($RoomId)
------------$($GUID)------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"

<h3>Testing...</h3>
------------$($GUID)------------
"@

$ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------$($GUID)------------"
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers     $Headers `
                            -Uri         $URI `
                            -Method      'Post' `
                            -Body        $Body `
                            -ContentType $ContentType$GUID = New-Guid

If I just want to post a text message using JSON, I am able to get it to work with [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]:
$Body = @{
           "roomId" = $RoomId
           "text"   = 'This is just a test'
         }

$Client  = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
$Content = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new()
$Content.Headers.Add('Authorization',"Bearer $($Token)")
$Content.RequestUri = $URI
$Content.Method = 'Post'

$UTF8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$Body = $($Body | ConvertTo-Json)
$Body = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($Body,$UTF8,'application/json')
$Content.Content = $Body
$Client.SendAsync($Content).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

However, my attempts at posting multipart/form-data using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient] have so far been unsuccessful.
I have tried the following:
$Body = @"
------------$($GUID)------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="roomId"

$($RoomId)
------------$($GUID)------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"

<h3>Testing with [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]</h3>
------------$($GUID)------------
"@

$Client  = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()
$Content = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new()
$Content.Headers.Add('Authorization',"Bearer $($Token)")
$Content.RequestUri = $URI
$Content.Method = 'Post'

$UTF8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$Body = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($Body,$UTF8,'multipart/form-data')
$Content.Content = $Body
$Client.SendAsync($Content).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

I do not receive an errors from the code, but the response I receive back is '400 - BadRequest'.

Try running a man-in-the-middle proxy like fiddler and use it to compare the http requests sent by both versions to see what the differences are. That might give you some pointers…

Different HTML libraries will automatically add different properties to the message.  For example User Agent and Content Length.  I like to use Postman to get code working because it is very robust and adds missing properties automatically.  Then once I get Postman working the control panel will show the entire request with added properties.  Then I can modify my non working code adding the missing items.



At least one problem with your approach of manually constructing the body is that you forgot to provide a boundary attribute as part of the Content-Type header that specifies the GUID that is used to separate the parts of the submission.

Insert the following statement after $Body = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($Body,$UTF8,'multipart/form-data')   (note that you cannot directly include this attribute in the constructor argument passed to [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new(...)):
$Body.Headers.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$guid`""


When using the dedicated .NET APIs (see next section), part-specific Content-Type headers get added too; to specify them manually inside your $Body string, add the following after each ------------$($GUID)------------ line (adjust the media type as needed, e.g. text/html):
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8




It is oversights such as these that make it preferable to use dedicated APIs, which implicitly ensure proper construction of the request body - see next section.



Use .NET's dedicated class for media type multipart/form-data, [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]:
Here is self-contained sample code that builds on yours; it works in both PowerShell editions:
# Load the relevant assembly.
# Note: Not strictly necessary in PowerShell (Core) 7: it is loaded by default.
Add-Type -Assembly System.Net.Http

# Sample input data
$roomId = 123
$htmlText = '<h3>Testing...</h3>'
$token = 'a1234c567' # authorization token
$url = 'https://00c78e52-4e81-4dcd-bbc4-0545b8f52ea8.requestcatcher.com'

# Construct the multi-part form data.
$multiPartFormData = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()

# Add the 1st part...
$partContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent] "$roomId"
# Note:  
#  * $partContent.Headers.ContentDisposition is automatically filled in as:
#      form-data; name=utf-8
#  * $partContent.Headers.ContentType is automatically filled in as:
#      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# Both these header fields can be overridden manually.
$multiPartFormData.Add($partContent, 'roomId')

# ... and another.
$partContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent] $htmlText
$multiPartFormData.Add($partContent, 'html')

# Create an HTTP client.
$client  = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new()

# Create a POST message with the target URL.
$message = [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage]::new('POST', $url)
# Add an authorization header.
$message.Headers.Add('Authorization', "Bearer $token")
# Assign the multi-part form data as the content (body).
$message.Content = $multiPartFormData

# Finally, send the message, synchronously (the equivalent of an
# Invoke-WebRequest call).
# Note:
#  * In PowerShell 7, you could more simply use:
#      $client.Send($message)
$client.SendAsync($message).GetAwaiter().GetResult()

# Clean up.
($multiPartFormData, $message, $client).Dispose()

The request will look something like this:
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 00c78e52-4e81-4dcd-bbc4-0545b8f52ea8.requestcatcher.com
Authorization: Bearer a1234c567
Content-Length: 322
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="22379103-e526-4115-8109-150d767bce0d"

--22379103-e526-4115-8109-150d767bce0d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=roomId

123
--22379103-e526-4115-8109-150d767bce0d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=html

<h3>Testing...</h3>
--22379103-e526-4115-8109-150d767bce0d--

Note:

The above uses a random requestcatcher.com URL  as the target URL.

If you open said URL (stored in the $url variable) in your browser prior to running the code, you can inspect each resulting request that is later submitted to that URL - that is how the request text posted above was obtained.


